# two Images and captions wont align AND spacing before and after the figure is too wide in two column conference paper

Tags: overleaf

I can't manage to align two images and their captions as shown below. The spacing before and after the figure is also too wide.
[image]

Here's the latex code I used:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{APSIPA2021}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[psamsfonts]{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% \begin{figure}[!htbp]
% \centering
% \subfloat[Rotated \( 180^o \)]{\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{Latex/bottle180.jpg}}\hfill
% \subfloat[Rotated \( 135^o \)]{\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{Latex/bottle135.jpg}}
% \caption{Attention map of a water bottle in different rotation angles.}
% \label{fig:naturalattention}
% \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/bottle180.jpg}
\caption{Rotated \( 180^o \)}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/bottle135.jpg}
\caption{Rotated \( 135^o \)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/bottle180.jpg}
\caption{Rotated \( 180^o \)}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/bottle135.jpg}
\caption{Rotated \( 135^o \)}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

I can't use `\usepackage{subcaption}` because it changes the caption style and fonts in figures and tables. I tried both `subfloat` and `minipage` but still failed.

Here's the paper kit that I used. https://www.apsipa2022.org/APSIPA_ASC_2022_Template.zip

Comment: Please complete the `\documentclass[]{????`

Comment: Welcome. // That's almost perfect: Can you please Edit your question and post the relevant end as well? This way we can copy, compile and see your problem.

Comment: I have edited the post. I added the paper kit that I used also. Need help.

Comment: I suspect your images include white space.  Put an \fbox{...} around \includegraphics to check.  (\fboxsep=0pt)